# Using PayPal for charge and refund on android

Tags: java, android, paypal

I’m trying to implement the in App refunds on android app.
Since the MPL  library doesn’t have an option for refund, I had to look for a workaround, following approaches checked:
Rewriting the rest api sdk java library in order to make it wotk on Android – get Sale returns ERROR 405, as if I was trying to download file named by transaction ID.
Tried to implement it by myself using just a part of the api sdk java library, in order to get access token.
Tried to implement CURL on android – but no success

Please anyone, can you give a direction on how to make it work?
If you can provide code examples, that would be great.